# How to setup routes when the controller only has edit and update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

**I can't seem to figure out how to get my routes setup properly.**

In my app, I have a view that lets site owners update their address information.  The **new** and **create** actions are part of the *signup process* and are located in the `signups_controller`.  The **edit** and **update** actions are in the `settings_controller`.

When the user goes into the settings area, he/she sees only the edit form.  When filled out, the user is then returned to the same form with a flash message, or error message.  **Here is what the controller looks like:**

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    @account = current_account
    @account.companies.first
    @account.companies.first.addresses.first
    @account.companies.first.phones.first
  end

  def update
    @account = current_account
    if @account.update_attributes(params[:account])
      redirect_to edit_setting_path
      flash[:notice] = "Success!"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

**In my routes, I simply have:**

```
resources :settings
```

**The link to this area of the site** is a basic RESTful named linke, with the parameter options:

```
edit_setting_path(:id => current_account.id)
```

**When the user arrives to this page, they see the following URL:**

```
http://domainname.com/settings/1/edit
```

**When they submit the form and get errors, the URL changes to:**

```
http://domainname.com/settings/1
```

Why is the URL changing -- I'd rather it not?  Is there a way to make it stay the same as the initial edit view?  I've tried doing a redirect on a failed update, but then I don't get the error messages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your "why" question: The URL is changing because it's reflecting the URL of the failed request - which in this case is a PUT request to that URL (/settings/1).  You've submitted the form and the submission of that form (correctly) points to that URL.  This is a result of the RESTful routes that the helper gives you.  Since the logic in your action, falls through to the render :action, there is no redirect and the form simply re-renders on the page using the same data available in this action (which is why you can see the errors).

If you want to redirect back to the edit page, yes, you will lose the errors that have been set in the @account instance variable since the redirect will reset (re-query for) the account.

You could add a route that matches a PUT to /settings/1/edit and point it to your update action and change your form etc.  In short, I wouldn't recommend this, but it should work.

completely untested but attemptable:

routes.rb

```
 put "/settings/:id/edit", :to=>"settings#update", :as=>"update_setting"
 resources :settings, :except=>:update
```

your form would also have to submit to the update_setting_path (which also means it's not reusable for a new object... ew)

Comment: Is there anyway to keep the errors but avoid changing the URL?

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick.  It doesn't seem like an uncommon scenario though -- am I wrong?  Also, if I use AJAX for the form, does this solve the problem as well?

Comment: No, not uncommon but i don't think it's really a problem unless you've got relative links or something on the page that are dependent on the current url. AJAX would not change the URL at all so I suppose it would solve the "problem", yes.

Answer (score 0):

First you should read up on [The Rails Guides for Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). They will help a lot to understand why its working like that.

Secondly, to accomplish what you are trying to do, you will need to add manual routes via the `match` call. You'll need something like this.

```
match '/settings/:id/edit' => "settings#edit"
```

Comment: This didn't change the behavior.

It added a new line in my routes:
`/settings/:id/edit(.:format)                   settings#edit`

But on a failed update, I'm still getting:
`http://domainname.com/settings/1`

Comment: Did you remove the resources setting?